# How to pass native event handler for interrupt in state pattern code

Tags: c#, delegates, embedded, interrupt-handling, .net-micro-framework

I've turned to state pattern for my netmf project. Something based on this: http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternState.aspx#_self2

I have a rotary encoder knob that will act differently in each state.

I've been trying to wrap my head around this and can't get anything to work on my end. I'm not sure where and how to inject the interrupt handler into each state and how to invoke the switch of the interrupt handler. Without the State Pattern the code looks something like:

```
RotaryEncoder RE = new RotaryEncoder(pin1, pin2);//create new instance of knob
RE.OnRotationEvent += OnRotationEventHandler;//subscribe to an event handler.
//do other things
...
...

static void OnRotationEventHandler(uint data1, uint data2, DateTime time)
        {
            //do something
        }
```

So, what's the right way to code have individual "OnRotationEventHandlers" for each state? Is it part of the context? Part of the abstract base class?

[image: Simple State Diagram]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It's not clear that an interrupt is the best mechanism for this.  If you really want to be directly interrupt-driven, then you should probably have the interrupt generically "pump" the state machine to act.  Personally, when I did things like this I had an interrupt handler capture the events to a small queue and then processed that asynchronously when I had time (which was quite soon in human terms) - it worked a lot like a traditional PC keyboard subsystem (and in fact accepted input from one in place of the knob for emulation).

Comment: @ChrisStratton Conceptually I understand what you're saying. NetMF also automatically Queues interrupts. I want the state to react to a rotation interrupt event. The interrupt can execute and "return" Clockwise or Counterclockwise. The state needs to know what happened and then react accordingly. Example, State1 is monitoring a sensor and then rotation event occurs and it's clockwise. State One Changes to State 2. The states could to poll a flag in a loop, but it seems inefficient. I can see other issues with that too..

Comment: Do you really need to do it this complexly? Isn't just enum with state and switch for next enough? And you can refactor it from there.

Comment: @Euphoric Maybe, but I don't quite follow. Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more research and here's the solution I've come up with:

I use "state" and "mode" interchangeably

Context Class:

```
    class ModeContext
    {
    private int rotationCount;
    private string direction;
    private State state;
    public RotaryEncoder rotaryEncoderInstance;


    public ModeContext( RotaryEncoder re)
    {
        this.State = new RPMMode(this);
        rotaryEncoderInstance = re;
        re.RotationEventHandler += OnRotationEvent;//attach to Context's Handler
        rotationCount = 0;
    }

    public State State
    {
        get { return state; }
        set { state = value; }//debug state change
    }

    //Event Handler        
    public void OnRotationEvent(uint data1, uint data2, DateTime time)
    {
        rotationCount++;
        if (data1 == 1) 
        { 
            direction = "Clockwise";
            state.OnCWRotationEvent(this);
        }
        else
        { 
            direction = "Counter-Clockwise";
            state.OnCCWRotationEvent(this);
        }
        Debug.Print(rotationCount.ToString() + ": " + direction + " Context Mode Rotation Event Fired!");
    }
```

Concrete State Class that Inherits The State Base class:

```
        class Mode2 : State
        {
        public override void Handle(ModeContext mode)
        {
            mode.State = new Mode2();//(mode);
        }

        public Mode2()
        {
            //do something;   
        }
        #region event handlers
        public override void OnCWRotationEvent(ModeContext mode)
        {
            mode.State = new Mode3(mode);
        }

        public override void OnCCWRotationEvent(ModeContext mode)
        {
            mode.State = new Mode1(mode);
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

Now that I can change state and give each state specific control behavior, where does the actual heavy lifting go?